# How to format output of results using output hooks in knitr?

Tags: r, knitr, beamer

I have a Rnw file `a.Rnw` with the following contents:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
<<>>=
1+1
@
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I produce a pdf by

```
Rscript -e 'knitr::knit("a.Rnw")'
pdflatex a.tex
```

The output in `a.pdf` looks like this:

[image: Output of knitr chunk]

How do I get the output to look like this:

```
R> 1+1
## [1] 2
```

That is, how do I put `R>` in front of the R code and remove the blank line between code and output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show `R>` in front of all R commands, I set the R prompt using `options` and tell knitr to show the prompt using `opts_chunk` (code at bottom of answer).

Getting rid of the new line is a bit trickier because the R code and R output in the generated tex file looks like this:

```
\begin{alltt}
\hlstd{R> }\hlnum{1}\hlopt{+}\hlnum{1}
\end{alltt}
\begin{verbatim}
## [1] 2
\end{verbatim}
```

So the newline between R code and its output is not generated explicitly by knitr, but is due to a new paragraph being started between `\end{alltt}` and `\begin{verbatim}`. The verbatim environment adds above and below it the current value of `\topsep` ([see here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/43336/82534%20see%20here)). So I patch the `knitrout` environment such that this variable is locally set to `0pt`. Here is the new version of `a.Rnw`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

% reduce whitespace between R code and R output
\let\oldknitrout\knitrout
\renewenvironment{knitrout}{
  \begin{oldknitrout}
  \topsep=0pt
}{
  \end{oldknitrout}
}

% show R> prompt before R commands
<<r setup, echo=FALSE>>=
options(prompt='R> ')
knitr::opts_chunk$set(prompt=TRUE) 
@

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
<<>>=
1+1
@
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

and the output looks like this:

[image: pdf generated by knitr with reduced whitespace between R code and output]

Comment: I've tried several methods to shrink R-output spacing: this is the first one that worked! ``\renewenvironment{knitrout}{etc.``